# Is it necessary to test the checksum when downloading a Linux installation DVD?

Tags: installation, fedora-15

I trying to install Fedora 15 on my system. I downloaded the DVD from the official Fedora download link. For downloading the ISO, I used [Orbit downloader](http://www.orbitdownloader.com/), but I did not test the checksum.

I burned the image and started the installation of Fedora, but after copying files (in the last step), it took a long time without any processing, then I got some error window.

Then my installation failed in the last step. Is Fedora 15 a stable version or not? If yes, then why did I get this error at end of the installation? Is it necessary to do a checksum verification of the ISO image? How can I test this checksum on Windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When burning installation DVDs, you **should** check the file and the DVD itself for errors. Otherwise problems such as those you described *could* happen.

Verification should ideally happen in two steps:

#### 1. Verify the downloaded ISO file for integrity

You need to make sure there weren't any errors during download. While this is rather uncommon, it could sometimes happen.

- Download the appropriate checksum file for your installation from the [Fedora Verification site](https://fedoraproject.org/verify) or copy the SHA1 checksum when you download the Fedora ISO.
- Also download [sha1sum for Windows](http://lists.gnupg.org/pipermail/gnupg-announce/2004q4/000184.html) for checking the SHA1 sum. You might also use [Microsoft's FCIV](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/841290).
- Put this `sha1sum.exe` and the Fedora ISO into the same folder.
- Then, go to Start → Run, enter "cmd".
- Use the `cd` command to go to the directory where you put the `sha1sum.exe` and the Fedora ISO.
- Run the following command:

  ```
  sha1sum.exe Fedora-15-i386-DVD.iso
  ```
- Compare the output of this command with the SHA1 sum of the download. If they're the same, you're fine.

There's a similar tutorial [here](http://www.labtestproject.com/using_windows/step_by_step_how_to_check_and_verify_fedora_10_iso_image).

#### 2. Verify the burned DVD for integrity

This is in my experience happening more often than download errors. You need to make sure the data on the DVD itself is exactly the same as the ISO file.

Depending on the software you used for burning, there should be an option to verify a DVD after burning. Look for it in the burning settings. If your DVD passed the verification, you should be fine.

Note that burning at lower speeds *can* lead to better results (i.e. less errors).